# Groovy new File command fails

Tags: groovy

I've been working with Groovy and Grails for a few weeks now with no problem.

I've just had a problem that any File creation command such as

```
def file = new File("test.txt")
```

just fails at runtime with

```
Class groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException
Message:Could not find matching constructor for: bcp.File(java.lang.String)
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Exception says it all. `bcp.File`. This is a custom implementation of `File` in package `bcp`.

Comment: Yes of course. Found the overriding class def thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
def file = new java.io.File("test.txt")
```

Comment: FYI: While your answer appears plausible, it has appeared in the 'low quality posts' queue after being flagged for deletion. I suspect this is because it is a code only answer without explanation.

Comment: @OliverMatthews He asked for help, not for explanation. To Explain without a ask for explanation is offensive from my POV. I see if its low-quality by inspect the up/downvotes aswell as from the question as the correct answer too. If a Op really need a qualified answer he will ask by a qualified question.

Comment: All I'm saying, is I'm seeing a lot of 'code only' answers getting flagged as low quality, so I've taken to putting a comment to that effect before hitting 'looks ok'.

Comment: @OliverMatthews Hey, its low-quality, no doubt. I can live with it, i am not unhappy - its fair.